# Deleted Ubuntu partition, stuck with GRUB rescue without recovery disks or BIOS password

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have an old laptop with Windows Vista Home and Ubuntu 11. So I decided to upgrade Ubuntu.

I had a separate partition which had Ubuntu installed on it. I deleted that partition.

Now, when I try to start my laptop, the GRUB shows its error console (**GRUB rescue**) and I am stuck.

To add to my troubles, my **BIOS is locked** and I don't remember the password. Also, I **no** longer have **recovery disks**.

I have some data on my Windows and would love to get it uncorrupted.

What should I do **without recovery discs and BIOS password** ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to take my laptop to a technician who reset the BIOS password.

GRUB should have a feature to at least let the healthy windows (if present) boot if it can't find Ubuntu.